# Add conditional choices to an argument if a specific choice for the first argument has been chosen discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot in Python. I only want the “second” choices to appear if I chose `2` for the “first” one.

**My code:**

```py
@client.hybrid_command()
@app_commands.Choices(first=[
    app_commands.Choice(name="1", value="1"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="2", value="2")
])
@app_commands.Choices(second=[
    app_commands.Choice(name="3", value="3"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="4", value="5"),
])
async def conditional(ctx, first, second):
    #The rest of my code
    ....
```

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: @Dominik I've seen other bots with that feature so are you sure or are you just guessing?

Comment: Which bot(s) are you referring to? The bot is not able to tell what you chose until you executed the command. Therefore, it's not able to limit your second choice based on the first one.

Comment: Tbh I don't remember the exact bot, but do you have another method I can do it with?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `Choice`, use autocomplete functions and the

```py
async def first_auto(interaction, current):
    return [
        app_commands.Choice(name="1", value="1"),
        app_commands.Choice(name="2", value="2")
    ]


async def second_auto(interaction, current):
    first_choice = interaction.namespace["first"]
    # return list of Choice based on `first_choice`
    if first_choice == "1":
        return [app_commands.Choice(name="First Choice", value="1st")]
    else:
        return [app_commands.Choice(name="Second choice", value="2nd")]


@app_commands.command()
@app_commands.autocomplete(first=first_auto, second=second_auto)
async def conditional(interaction, first, second):
    ...
```

It's not possible to do this with hybrid commands though.

Comment: Is there any way I can do it with a slash command? (Now I may be stupid but isn't a hybrid command the only way I can make a slash command?)

Comment: No, this is already a slash command. You don’t need to make it hybrid.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see if I can get it working later! I have to rewrite most of my code tho but I'd assume this is more efficient.